# Extract string from another string in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, substring

i have a table in which i save form html which include image also like this

```
<img src="../UploadedFiles/2143_logo.png" >
<img src="../UploadedFiles/2343_New_logo.jpeg" >
<img src="../UploadedFiles/2786_old_logo.bmp" >
```

i want to extract image name for each record like this

```
2143_logo.png

2343_New_logo.jpeg

2786_old_logo.bmp
```

i don't know how to get it done please help me out

thanks in advance

Comment: Is the image tag the only thing in the field, or is it jus a part of a larger html "blob"?

Comment: Then I'm sorry to say that you can probably create a horrible horrible hack that solves your problem, but it's definitely not a problem SQL is made for :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very ugly way to do this:

```
select 
  replace(replace(reverse(left(reverse(yourColumn), charindex('/', reverse(yourColumn)) -1)), '>', ''), '"', '')
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fa05/12)

Comment: well it is giving me error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: @rahul that is strange, it is working on the SQL Fiddle. Can you create a SQL Fiddle with some additional data and post the link here?

Comment: problem is that my html is not in fix format as i have mentioned on top it is just a part of random html.